# Draw.io: How to change the line height of text in multiple vertices at once?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

In draw.io I have a large number of flowchart boxes containing text. Selecting multiple boxes let's you change the font size, spacing etc. of many at once, but it seems to change the "line height" option to raise or lower the spacing between lines you have to individually select the text in each box and change the percentage one item at a time.
I have hundreds of vertices so one at a time will take a while. Any way around this?